# GNU R output file format for AIP (PRB) journal

Tags: r, templates, ggplot2, journal

How should a minimal template for GNU R (ggplot2) plots look like, if they should be published in the AIP PR journal family?

A [set of requirements](http://www.aip.org/epub/submitgraph.html) is listed on the AIP Website and in the [Physical Review Style and Notation Guide](https://publish.aps.org/files/styleguide-pr.pdf). 
I would prefer TIFF or PNG files, as PDF and PS files do not support all graphic objects today.
This is my minimal example so far:

```
library(ggplot2)

theme_prb <- theme_bw()
## have to find out how to create own theme with
## fontsize=12 and so on.

theme_set(theme_prb)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=qsec)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_hline(yintercept=mean(mtcars$qsec)) 

ggsave(filename="00001prb.png", dpi=600, scale=1, units="mm", width=86, height=60)
```

Comment: You should have some ideas. Even if it doesn't get you the whole way, show us what you got.

Comment: nothing wrong with pdf/eps and Phys Rev; what "graphic objects" aren't supported today?

Comment: @baptiste ggplot PDF and PS output files look different from the screen output. Very problematic are embedded fonts, mathematical formulas and the alpha channel and there are even more problems. (At least when I tried it in end of 2012.)

Comment: I haven't had problems, though admittedly I often tweak the final version in Illustrator. Could you post a minimal mockup example with all the features you find missing in the pdf/eps output?

Comment: @baptiste yes I can create such an example. But it will have to wait a bit. I will create a separate thread for it and give a link here.